# What's a noun for a cause of a bad effect?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What is a noun for an action or thing that negatively influences another? For example,

> If you don't keep up with your school assignments, all the **bad grades** you've accumulated will overwhelm you at the end of the year.
>
> The economy has been a big **?** for our organization.
>
> One **?** to the driver was that his tires were going flat.
>
> Writing them an angry letter would be a big **?** for our group.

I'm looking to replace the bold words and question marks. *Inauspicious* would work, but I need a noun.

Comment: The economy has been a big **minus** for our organization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"detriment" would work for the second and fourth examples, "The economy has been a big detriment ..." and "... would be a big detriment ...". I've never heard it used in the plural so I don't know that it would work in your second example. It vaguely doesn't sound right in the third example though I can't quite say why not.

Comment: It sounds fine in the third example to me.

Answer (score 6):

*[Liability](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/liability)* could work. It simply means *something disadvantageous*, so I think that it would work well in some of your examples:

> The economy has been a big *liability* to our organization.

Or:

> Writing them an angry letter would be a big *liability* for our group.

But I don't think that this one sounds very nice, even though it might be correct:

> One *liability* to the driver was that his tires were going flat.

Answer (score 1):

With minimal rewriting, you can use simply *bad* or the more hoity-toity *prove [disadvantageous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disadvantageous)* or perhaps *[setback](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/setback)* (or *obstacle, delay, disadvantage*) in your examples.  In following, the first right arrow (→) sets off examples rewritten with *bad* or *prove disadvantageous*, and the second arrow sets off more-thorough rewrites.

*Example:* "The economy has been a big ? for our organization" → "The economy has been bad for our organization" or "The economy has proven disadvantageous for our organization"→ "The economy sandbagged our organization" or "The economy dealt our organization mortal wounds."

*Example:* "One ? to the driver was that his tires were going flat" → "A setback for the driver was that his tires were going flat" or "It was bad for the driver that his tires were flat"  → "The driver's ontime record collapsed as his tires went flat."

*Example:* "Writing them an angry letter would be a big ? for our group" →  "Writing them an angry letter would be a serious setback for our group"  "Writing them an angry letter would prove disadvantageous  for our group"  → "Writing them an angry letter would provide our group tremendous spiritual comfort and no end of grief."

*Comment:*  I suggest posting questions like yours in [writers.stackexchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com), suitably revised to ask about how best to phrase your examples.  Trying to shoehorn a single word into these disparate slots is a mistake; your effort would be better spent rewriting the sentences in less-clumsy forms.

Comment: +1, but suggestion: move the sentence about writers.SE to a comment and out of this answer.

Comment: @jprete I've moved that bit to end of answer, but not out; I think it's a reasonable part of answers to questions where rewording is as important as vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

[**Impediment**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/impediment) will work in your examples (the first one needs minor rewriting to use it).  It means *obstruction; hindrance; obstacle*.

> If you don't keep up with your school assignments, all the bad grades you've accumulated will be an *impediment* to you at the end of the year.
>
> The economy has been a big *impediment* for our organization.
>
> One *impediment* to the driver was that his tires were going flat.
>
> Writing them an angry letter would be a big *impediment* for our group.